# Ajax load page content in div but keep the "open in new tab" on right click

Tags: javascript, ajax, tabs, right-click

I'm working on a new website with a mysql database that sort a bunch of items in different categories and subcategories. I created a cool script that load dynamically the content of the category (page content) in a div without reloading the page. When you load the content, it also changes the url in the address bar and if you reload the page from this url, you will see the content of the right category. The thing is that I want to keep the "open in new tab" on right clik that every browser provides and I don't find a way to have it because the content is loaded from a javascript/ajax function.

I thought that

```
<a href="javascript: liveresults('mycategory');">
```

would work instead of

```
<a onclick="liveresults('mycategory');">
```

but the "open in new tab" doesn't show up in firefox and give a "about:blank" page in chrome. In Firefox, if I keep CTRL pressed and then click, it works but the url is "javascript:%20liveresults('mycategory');" and I don't know what to do next.

Is there someone having an idea about how should I proceed? Maybe I should try to create my own custom right click menu like http://grooveshark.com/

Comment: If it changes url in address bar, just write `<a href='new url' onclick='javascript...'>`. And teach your page to open needed category depending on received url.

Comment: If I do that, the page won't reload?

Comment: No, if javascript code in `onclick` returns `false`.

Comment: It's working great but usually, you can also hold the control button and click to open the link in a new tab and this is not working. Do you have an idea to fix it? I tried something like: if(event.ctrlKey == 1){ window.open(url, "_blank"); } but there is no way to prevent the focus on the new tab.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function loadContent(event, param) {
    if (!event.ctrlKey) {
        console.log(param)
        return false
    } else
        return true
}

<a
  href='http://google.com'
  onclick='return loadContent(event, "category")'
>Testo</a>
```

I think, no need to explain.
Also, style aspect, I would suggest you to do it this way:

```
function loadContent(event) {
    if (!event.ctrlKey) {
        console.log(event.target.dataset.category)
        return false
    } else
        return true
}

<a
  href='http://google.com'
  onclick='return loadContent(event)'
  data-category='my_category'
>Testo</a>
```

It may not work in old IEs (which has srcElement instead of target), but in my opinion looks cooler. But doesn't matter really.

Or, actually (maybe it's too much =) you could get rid of double specifying the address:

```
function loadContent(event) {
    if (!event.ctrlKey) {
        var part_of_url = event.target.href.split('/')[3]
        // maybe some other extraction method, now 'mail'
        console.log(part_of_url)
        return false
    } else
        return true
}

<a
  href='http://google.com/mail/'
  onclick='return loadContent(event)'
>Testo</a>
```